# When using Postgres Enum types with Rails, specifying CREATE TYPE xyz_setting AS ENUM in your migration breaks your db/schema.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, enums

this is based on some dev.to articles here https://dev.to/diegocasmo/using-postgres-enum-type-in-rails-30mo
and here https://dev.to/amplifr/postgres-enums-with-rails-4ld0
and the same guy's article here https://medium.com/@diegocasmo/using-postgres-enum-type-in-rails-799db99117ff

If you follow the advice above, you are advised to create a Rails schema migration for your Postgres backed schema by using `CREATE TYPE xyz_setting AS ENUM` directly on Postgres, and then use that to create your new field as an ENUM (a postgres enum)

Unfortunately, this approach has the downside of breaking the `db/schema.rb` file.

I think the problem is that the native Postgres types are not supported by the Rails core.

I can reproduce the behavior on Rails 5.17, 5.2.2.4, and 6.0.3

if I do...

```
class AddXyzToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-DDL
          CREATE TYPE xyz_setting AS ENUM (
            'apple', 'bananna', 'cherry'
          );
    DDL
    add_column :users, :xyz, :xyz_setting
  end

  def down
    remove_column  :users, :xyz
    execute "DROP type xyz_setting;"
  end
end
```

then my schema file is messed up, specifically, the schema users table doesn't get output whatseover, and instead in its place is this message

## Could not dump table "users" because of following StandardError

## Unknown type 'xyz_setting' for column 'xyz'

Comment: Did you try setting `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` in the environment configuration files?

Comment: I wondering if this gives error why its on rails [official documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#enumerated-types)? 
`

Comment: consider to just use normal string since rails enum now support hash/string mapping https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Custom enum types in PostgreSQL (Rails 7+)

[Rails 7 added support for custom enum types in PostgreSQL](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41469).

So now, a migration can be written as follows:

```rb
# db/migrate/20131220144913_create_articles.rb
def up
  create_enum :article_status, ["draft", "published"]

  create_table :articles do |t|
    t.enum :status, enum_type: :article_status, default: "draft", null: false
  end
end

# There's no built in support for dropping enums, but you can do it manually.
# You should first drop any table that depends on them.
def down
  drop_table :articles

  execute <<-SQL
    DROP TYPE article_status;
  SQL
end
```

It is also worth mentioning, when you use [`create_enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-create_enum), the enum definitions and enum columns will be presented in `schema.rb`.

**Sources**:

- [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41469).
- [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#enumerated-types).
- [Rails API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter.html#method-i-create_enum).
- [Rails 7 adds better support for custom enum types in PostgreSQL](https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/01/12/rails-7-adds-custom-enum-support-in-postgresql) by [Saeloun](https://blog.saeloun.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Rails doesn't support custom PG types out of the box.

As stated by [Diego Castillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64668994/when-using-postgres-enum-types-with-rails-specifying-create-type-xyz-setting-as#comment114346028_64668994) you can use a sql schema which will handle those types.

However, if you want to keep using a ruby schema there's [activerecord-postgres_enum](https://github.com/bibendi/activerecord-postgres_enum), a gem that provides support for PostgreSQL enum data types.

Comment: for information about "SQL schema" see https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 7 if you are using PostgreSQL you can now do:

```
rails generate model Post title:string body:text post_type:enum
```

Your migration can be like:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_enum :post_option, ["draft", "private", "published"]
    
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.enum :post_type, enum_type: "post_option", default: "draft", null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :posts, :post_type
  end
end
```

Your schema would look like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_06_04_221707) do
  ...
  create_enum "post_option", ["draft", "private", "published"]
  ...
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title", default: ""
    t.text "body", default: ""
    t.enum "post_type", default: "draft", null: false, enum_type: "post_option"
    t.string "image", default: ""
    t.index ["post_type"], name: "index_posts_on_post_type"
  end
end
```

Then, on your model you need to add:

```
enum :post_type, draft: "draft", private: "private", published: "published"
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Rails 7 Postgres enum support is now built-in**

I like @crysicia's answer a lot but to be more precise for the next developer, **for Rails 6** you have the choice of either:

1. using  [activerecord-postgres_enum](https://github.com/bibendi/activerecord-postgres_enum)
2. SWITCHING your Rails app to SQL schema (assuming you are using the native Rails schema at `db/schema.rb`) which instead produces `db/structure.sql` and will write your schema in native SQL of course.

The #2 approach is frowned upon by the Rails-DB separation purists, of course, but as-is this entire implementation anyway since I don't know of other Dbs that support the enum anyway (there may be).

So basically if you want to keep `db/schema.rb` I'd recommend using the [activerecord-postgres_enum](https://github.com/bibendi/activerecord-postgres_enum) gem

Comment: even better just use normal string since rails enum now support hash/string mapping https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: I thought the point was to have parity with the support for Postgresql's implementation of enum which will search faster than strings